# apt autoremove trying to remove essential packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I recently ran

```
apt install build-essential libncurses5-dev libpcap-dev libgtkmm-3.0-dev autoconf autopoint intltool libxml2-utils
```

as an application dependencies because it was mentioned in the website. But after I'm done with application I ran

```
sudo apt purge build-essential libncurses5-dev libpcap-dev libgtkmm-3.0-dev autoconf autopoint intltool libxml2-utils
```

But after that `apt` gives a large autoremove list

```
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu icoutils kate-data katepart kde-runtime-data kde-style-breeze
  kde-style-breeze-qt4 kdelibs-bin krita-data libatk-bridge2.0-dev
  libatk1.0-dev libatkmm-1.6-dev libatspi2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libepoxy-dev
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libgtk-3-dev
  libkatepartinterfaces4 libkdcraw-data libkdcraw23 libkde3support4
  libkdeclarative5 libkdesu5 libkemoticons4 libkf5style5 libkjsembed4
  libkmediaplayer4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkpty4 libkxmlrpcclient4
  libllvm4.0 libnl-route-3-200 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libopencolorio1v5
  libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-4 libqt4-designer libqt4-qt3support
  libtinfo-dev libtinyxml2.6.2v5 libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev
  libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev libxtst-dev libyaml-cpp0.3v5
  linux-headers-4.10.0-40 linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-104 linux-headers-4.4.0-104-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-40-generic linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-40-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-40-generic nettle-dev ntrack-module-libnl-0
  oxygen-icon-theme oxygen5-icon-theme plasma-scriptengine-javascript
  x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-record-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev xsltproc
```

But I know these packages are important. I again installed previously removed packages. But still showing large list of packages to be removed.How to resolve this?

Comment: if apt says they are no longer used, then they can be removed. Are you using the KDE desktop? And which kernel are you using?

Comment: @ravery Can `linux-image` be removed safely?

Comment: if you are using a newer one, which you probably are, then yes

Comment: @ravery I'm using gnome-desktop. Yes I'm using newer `linux-image`. I can remove this. But what about others?

Comment: the listed packages are for KDE, or development packages; and old kernels. it is safe to let apt remove them since apt says that nothing is using them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a package is installed dependencies and sometimes recommends also get installed. Removing the package doesn't always remove all the packages that were installed with it. For example, I can see from the list that you had `krita` installed at one time. It is a KDE package. But when it was removed, pieces of KDE software were left behind.

Anything starting with "libk" is a KDE desktop package, and unneeded for gnome. Anything ending ins "-dev" is a develpoment package, most are unneeded unless you are developing software. The normal packages are sufficient.

I normally keep the current kernel and the one previous. All others can be deleted.

Since all the listed packages fall under this category and apt list them as unused by other packages, it is safe to remove them.

```
apt-get autoremove #this will remove packages that were autoinstalled that are no longer used by another package.
```

Answer (score 1):

**You are purging `build-essential` and some other essential packages for other dependencies.**

So if you mark them to purge using `apt` it automatically also removes/purges **all** packages which depend on them!

---

I'ld recommend to never purge multiple packages in one command (unless you know what you're doing) but rather one by one. So you have more control over what else gets purged.

---

My guess it that very probably for some of the packages when you ran the first command to install it mentioned that they already have been installed before.

Of course you don't want to purge those that were installed before because this might cause other packages depending on them to be purged as well (as in your case).

---

For the `linux-headers` and `linux-image` packages as already mentioned in the comments it is usually save since `apt` recognizes that you have newer ones installed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encounter a same type of problem after remove some packages. There is nothing to afraid if system is currently running well and after restart the machine. `apt autoremove` removes packages which have no dependency currently.

Answer (score 0):

I am an inexperienced Linux user, but I just had this situation arise and I believe it is NOT safe [for inexperienced users].

I recently ran 'sudo apt autoremove' after installing R and RStudio - I noticed a bunch of programs that I use frequently (like QGIS) in a long list that apt said were "no longer required" - and... my QGIS installation is gone, and since I closed the terminal I have no idea what other packages were removed.

My suggestion [for inexperienced users] is to selectively remove the really old linux kernel, headers and images (leaving some recent ones in case you have to revert) - see user353733's explanation and cl-Netbox's suggestion at https://askubuntu.com/a/1076329/992284, but don't let apt decide what's "no longer required," expecially if you see a bunch of things you use alot and don't want to spend the rest of the night figuring out what happened to your software and why you can't reinstall the software or it's dependencies.

[Image of Synaptic Package Manager, apparently unable to reinstall software removed with apt autoremove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az8Hn.png)