# Is removing old linux-headers and linux-image packages safe?

Tags: apt, kernel

I started using Ubuntu and like it so far.

I got my first system at a point where problems would really hurt.

Normally I do the `apt-get upgrade` stuff quite brain-off but this here made me feel a bit uncertain.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

I believe that newer version of this modules are installed and used already and that this old ones can be removed. But that is just me theory. When running autoremove it says that 335 MB will be freed.

Is this safe or not?

**Update:** I went for the autoremove with purge (even if I have enough space) I just seem to be greedily. It then popped up a purple screen asking me:

A new version of /boot/grub/menu.lst is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified.
What would you like to do about menu.lst?

- install the package maintainer's version
- keep the local version currently installed
- show the differences between the versions
- show a side-by-side difference between the versions
- show a 3-way difference between available versions
- do a 3-way merge between available versions (experimental)
- List item start a new shell to examine the situation

if I choose option 2: keep the local version, will it keep revert back to 4.15.0-29?
what should I do.
I'm sure this is just a small thing but I dont want this system to have short or longterm issues.

**Update:**
I compared both versions: one was the grub list and the other was some tmp list.
one was version 29 and the other had version 34. I pressed: keep the local version currently installed twice and rebootet.

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-34-generic
```

hope that grub list is okay and its not the tmp list.

Nevertheless I wanted to thank all you guys for the amount of very detailed answers. I felt a bit bad for all the time you spent answering me the initial question.
But this seems to stand up for a decent community.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Usually Ubuntu removes old kernels when enough successive versions are installed. You can check with `uname -r` which version you're running. If you _never_ rebooted and your running kernel is indeed `4.15.0-29`, I suggest to reboot to use a more recent version before removing it.

Comment: Perfectly safe.  Though I personally keep one or two old versions behind in case I find a problem with the current version.  That is, I select the older version at the grub screen.  But if I've been using the current version for some time (i.e., after a few restarts and everything seems fine), I do tend to remove the old ones.  Mind you, if you have a fairly recent computer and a fairly recent hard disk, then 335 MB isn't a whole lot.  So I do this kind of clean-up once a year or so...

Comment: but what do I choose in the purple screen:

Comment: install the package maitainer's version / keep the local verion currently installed / show differences between the versions / ...I think keep the local verion is the best or not ?

Comment: YOU made a change in that software's configuration. Only you can determine if you want to keep that change or not. If in doubt, install the package maintainer's version. If you don't notice a change in the software, then the change was irrelevant. If you do notice different behavior, then you will recall what change you made and why...and you can restore the change.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it's safe.**

And here's how to determine the answer for yourself using the `uname` command:

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-34-generic
```

In this case, you can see that my running system is 4.15.0-34, several versions above -29. So if my hardware works properly on -34, then -29 is safe to remove. Ubuntu retains older kernel versions so that you can still boot your system in case a new kernel causes problems (it's very rare, but has happened)

**Let's take a step back** and look at the proposed removals a bit more carefully:

```
linux-headers-*
linux-image-*
```

*image* packages are what your system runs - they are binaries. Those are the important ones.

*header* packages are used to compile kernels and modules. They are not executable, and can be removed at any time.

**Finally, let's explain** what's going on under the hood: There is some package-management magic, and a really clever script tying it all together.

Apt manages your kernel *images* using a metapackage, typically the `linux-image-generic` metapackage.

When a new kernel is released, the metapackage is updated with a new dependency, and apt downloads that new dependency (the new kernel package).

A post-install script triggers GRUB to update and for you to get that "you should reboot" notification.

Another post-install script marks some (not all) older kernels as eligible for removal.

The next time apt runs, it notices that those older kernel packages are orphaned and eligible for autoremoval, and tells you so.

Ubuntu has used that post-install script to mark older kernel packages for quite a few years now, with great success. It keeps the newest kernel, and the currently-running kernel (just in case), and sometimes one older kernel. The script keeps your /boot from filling up with lots of old images - one image can be over 300 MB! On space-constrained, LLVM, and encrypted systems, /boot is often a separate partition, so keeping that space free is important!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Michael - it is completely safe to remove this old kernel. By default Ubuntu keeps two kernels - the current one and the one before. One set of kernel packages uses about 335 MB disk space and that's why you receive the information about the freed space. To completely remove those old kernel packages, including all configuration files, execute this command (`purge` instead of `autoremove`) :

```
sudo apt purge linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic
```

Answer (score 1):

*I will explain how Ubuntu manages kernels before attempting to answer your question.*

APT will always keep only the 2 latest kernels installed in your system. Ubuntu runs on the latest kernel and keep the other for backup.

For example, consider you have 4.15.0-29 and 4.15.0-33 currently installed. The latest will be activated by default unless you modified your grub. So you would be running Ubuntu on 4.15.0-33 and 4.15.0-29 is left for backup.

When you install a newer version, for example, 4.15.0-34, with `apt upgrade` apt will see that there now 3 versions in your system and mark the oldest one as "no longer required".

Since you weren't running your Ubuntu on that kernel anyway before you upgraded, it would be pretty safe to remove the old kernel with `sudo apt autoremove` as 4.15.0-33 would now become the backup.

Tip: You can add `--purge` to the command to completely remove the old kernels and not leave any traces and save even more space.

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

Comment: I did the sudo apt autoremove --purge and a purple screen apeared telling me that a new version of /boot/grup/menu.lst is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified. then there are some options :( dont wont to wreck this thing :)

Comment: Usually when this happens, `apt` gives you the option to view differences, I would select that option and see what's the diff. (In this case, keeping the current file may be the correct route, but I would still check the diff first)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is perfectly safe, it is meant to clean up unused kernels.
If you do :

```
ls /boot
```

in a terminal you can see there are more than two versions of the kernel.
Ubuntu keeps 2 normally, so you can go back one version.
If you have more than 2,

`sudo apt autoremove`

will clean the oldest up, as other packages that are left and no longer used because of changed dependencies.